# Limit of sequence of Riemann integrable functions is not Riemann integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

This post is to clarify if the following example works. Let ${q_n}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$.

For each n define $f_n(x)=1$ if $x\in\{q_1,...,q_n\}$ and $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise.
Then for all n $\int f_n dx=0$ while $\int f dx$ does not exist where $lim_{n}f_n=f$ and $f$ is the Dirichlet function.

Is this valid?

Comment: yes it is correct. Notice that a countable enumeration of $\mathbb Q$ is a tautology.

Comment: I always thought enumeration just meant "indexed over some set" but thanks.

Comment: @JhonDoe Yes, but if "enumeration" means that each elements appears only once, then any enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.